# Sellar un XML para facturación 4.0 SAT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

esta pregunta la realizo en español ya que el problema se trata sobre un servicio de facturación mexicano. El problema presentado es el siguiente:

Actualmente se factura y timbra de manera correcta sobre la versión 3.3 e incluso sobre la versión 4.0 sin embargo cuando el cliente en su nombre tiene caracteres especiales como la ñ siempre se obtiene la respuesta de El sello del emisor es inválido, asumo puede ser algo al momento de encriptar con la llave en sha 256 o bien al codificar la respuesta en base 64, sin embargo no encuentro soporte en algún sitio con este tipo de problema, si pudieran ayudarme les agradeceria

Actualmente se utiliza dicho código para firmar el cual funciona para v3.3 y v4.0 excepto caracteres especiales

```
Base64::encode64(self.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new, cadena_original)).gsub(/\n/, '')
```

Las pruebas que he intentado realizar sin éxito es cambiar las Ñ por N como se realizaba en v 3.3, cambiar las Ñ de la cadena original por codificación &Ntilde, ambas sin éxito ya que obtengo - El campo Nombre del receptor, debe pertenecer al nombre asociado al RFC registrado en el campo Rfc del Receptor

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Procura incluir todo el código relevante y mensajes de error completos, no sólo un resumen. No sabemos qué hace el método `sign` para que otros puedan indicar dónde tratar la cadena (escaparla u otra cosa). Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Me sumo a lo dicho por Alfabravo, dificil poder ayudar sin un código de ejemplo